# Raspberry Pi model information - 2018 vs 2019

Tags: pi-4, pi-models

I bought a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB - 2019 model from [amazon](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07XSJ64ZY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) The seller says the model is 2019

[image]

But in the Pi circuit board its mentioned 2018.

[image]

So did I receive an old model or does the circuit board always say the year as `2018` ?

Comment: That's the date the design for the 4B (ver 1) was done. It took a year from design to production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cat /proc/device-tree/model` will show details.
My original Pi4 shows **Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1**

I believe later models with USB fix are Rev 1.2.

The Pi4 was announced on 24 Jun 2019 - there never was a 2018 model, although the board design may be 2018.

Comment: The command prints `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2`